# What does the word [執こく]{しつこく} mean?

Tags: words

This sentence is about cats:

> こちらからも**執こく**しないで、そっと放任して置いてやれば、猫はいよいよ猫らしく美しくなって、無言の愛着を飼主に寄せて来るのである。

A number of other examples can be found [here](http://yourei.jp/%E5%9F%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%8F).

Comment: Not given with the kanji, but [しつこい](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A4%E3%81%93%E3%81%84) seems to mean "obstinate, tenacious", which matches with the meaning of the kanji [執](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%9F%B7%20%23kanji).

Answer (score 3):

しつこく is an adverbial form of the adjective しつこい meaning "persistent", "stubborn", "obstinate".

An alternative spelling is used in the examples given. See for example [Weblio for しつこい](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A4%E3%81%93%E3%81%84):

> しつ こ・い ［3］
>   （ 形 ） ［文］ ク しつこ・し
>   **〔「執拗い」とも書く〕**

Answer (score 0):

In this context "執こくしない" has the opposite meaning of "(そっと)放任して置いてやる（放任して置く）."

"執こくする" in this context is "taking too much care of a cat too much."

I think this phrase is also sometimes used for a girlfriend or boyfriend in reference to someone who is clingy.